# Everytime data is inserted in branch table i want to create a table. but the name should come from branch table ifsccode column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

To create branch table:

```
CREATE TABLE Branch    
(    
    bId int PRIMARY KEY,    
    bName varchar(20),    
    bCity varchar(20),    
    ifscCode varchar(15)    
)
```

Procedure so to create a table with dynamic table name. Table name is the last inserted value of `ifsccode` column inserted in branch table. So that every time data is inserted into the `Branch` table, another table with that `ifscCode` name should get created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spName
AS    
    DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(200), @Query VARCHAR(7000)

    SET @tableName = 'SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC'

BEGIN    
    SET @Query = 'create table ' + @tableName + ' ( bId int, tokenDate date,
slot int, uToken int,username varchar(30),    
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES UserDetails(username),    
FOREIGN KEY (bId) REFERENCES Branch(bId)    
)'

    EXECUTE (@Query)
END
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO Branch 
VALUES (1, 'Bandra', 'Mumbai', 'BOI650011')
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'bId'

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: `set @tableName='SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC'` should be `SELECT TOP 1 @tableName = ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC`

Comment: or `set @tableName= (SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC)`

Comment: ^^ Hardly any point using `SET` + `SELECT` when just `SELECT` will do though right? :) Either way the quotes aren't required because that bit of SQL isn't dynamic.

Comment: This is clearly SQL Server from the messages. As for what you *want* to do, there is only one answer: Don't. This type of design will only come to haunt you later. Normalise your design, don't have one table per branch. Such designs are terrible to work with and perform awfully.

Answer (score 0):

Storing table names in columns is generally a bad idea.  My general thoughts on the matter are that if you do it, you should have such a strong understanding of SQL that a question like this would never occur.

In any case, you would see your problem immediately if you printed out the SQL.  It would look something like this:

```
'CREATE TABLE SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC . . . '
```

The issue is this line:

```
set @tableName = 'SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC';
```

You are setting the value of `@tableName` to a string.  You want the actual value:

```
set @tableName = (SELECT TOP 1 ifscCode FROM Branch ORDER BY bId DESC);
```